# Don't redraw some of the view structure

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

Consider the following code that draws a grid of randomly colored rectangles on the screen, with a Circle that moves to right by responding to a timer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let width: CGFloat = 400
    let height: CGFloat = 400
    let spacing: CGFloat = 8.0
    let numRows = 20
    var tileSize: CGFloat {
        height / 5
    }
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var circleX: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        let numColumns = Int(tileSize)
        
        ZStack {
            Grid(horizontalSpacing: spacing, verticalSpacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(0..<numRows, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                    GridRow {
                        ForEach(0..<numColumns, id: \.self) { colIndex in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.random)
                                .frame(width: tileSize, height: tileSize)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width:50, height: 50)
                .offset(x: circleX, y: 0)
                
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            circleX += 10
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        Color(red: .random(in: 0...1),
              green: .random(in: 0...1),
              blue: .random(in: 0...1))
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't want the rectangles to change color. I want them to get a random color to start with and stay that way. What currently happens is that every time the timer is fired, the rectangles all get a new color. The whole view is being re-rendered even though I'm only changing a property that applies to the circle. I've tried putting the `.onReceive` modifier on the Circle itself but that doesn't help.

Comment: If you haven’t seen it, I might suggest watching WWDC 2021’s [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022). It really helped me understand the view lifecycles in SwiftUI. Also 2023’s [Demystify SwiftUI performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160) expands on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract a separate view for the randomly-coloured rectangle.

```
struct RandomlyColoredRectangle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.random)
    }
}
```

This works because the `Color.random` call is in another `body`. When SwiftUI calls `ContentView.body`, `RandomlyColoredRectangle.body` is not called because no dependencies of `RandomlyColoredRectangle` has changed (in fact it has no dependencies).

---

The more general way to prevent view updates is to conform to `Equatable`:

```
struct RandomlyColoredRectangle: View, Equatable {
    // since this struct has no properties, the automatically generated '=='
    // always returns true

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.random)
    }
}
```

and use `RandomlyColoredRectangle` like this:

```
RandomlyColoredRectangle().equatable()
```

`equatable()` makes it so that the view only updates when the new `RandomlyColoredRectangle` is unequal to the old `RandomlyColoredRectangle`. Since our `==` always return true, the view never updates.

This is more flexible as you can implement `==` in your own way, so that the view only updates when you want it to.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `@State` to the color property in the RandomlyColoredRectangle struct works, although I'm still not quite sure why.