# How to achieve that only selected item in LazyHStack is redrawn

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this `LazyHStack` and a few items in it. Now what I have noticed, is that every time I tap on an item (I draw a border around it) the whole hstack is redrawn along with all items in it (I added rainbow debug so I see it visually it re-renders).

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI

private let rainbowDebugColors = [Color.purple, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.orange, Color.red]

extension View {
    func rainbowDebug() -> some View {
        self.background(rainbowDebugColors.randomElement()!)
    }
}

enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case first = "first"
    case second = "second"
    case third = "third"
    case fourth = "fourth"
    case fifth = "fifth"
}

struct MyModel: Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let type: MyEnum

    init(type: MyEnum) {
        self.id = type.rawValue
        self.type = type
        self.title = type.rawValue.uppercased()
    }
}

final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var selection: MyEnum?
    let types: [MyModel] = MyEnum.allCases.map { MyModel(type: $0) }
}

struct MyItemView: View {

    let model: MyModel
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 130)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)

                        .stroke(isSelected ? .purple : .clear, lineWidth: 3)
                )
            VStack {
                Text(model.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .rainbowDebug()
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            isSelected.toggle()
         }
    }
}

struct MySelectorView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.types, id: \.type) { model in
                        MyItemView (
                            model: model,
                            isSelected: Binding(get: {
                                viewModel.selection == model.type
                            }, set: { value in
                                viewModel.selection = model.type
                            })
                        )
                    }
                }
            .frame(height: 120)
            .padding()
        }.rainbowDebug()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        MySelectorView()
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to affect only one selected item in my `hstack`?

This is from Instruments...[image: Instruments image]

I know this maybe can't be an issue for 20-30 items with some simple data, but it seems inefficient.

Comment: Why do you think `MySelectorView` should *not* be updated? Its dependency `viewModel` has been changed, after all.

Comment: Cause its seems kinda expensive. I know it changes cause selection changes. But like I thought there is some way to avoid redrawing of a whole selector view. Imagine if I had 100 items and redraws would happen just cause of one element.

Comment: Also note that this is just a view update. The view is not destroyed and recreated again, as you might have implied.

Comment: It's not as expensive as you might think. SwiftUI evaluates `body`, and compares the difference the new `body` and what it was previously, and only updates the parts that are different.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with update vs destroyed. If you run the Instruments, a lot of redraws can be seen, and incrementing at each tap (even on a same item)...

Comment: @Sweeper So, you say SwiftUI will only update the parts that are different. rainbowDebug shows that whole selector changes along all items in it, not just that selected item.. Or I am not understanding what you are saying.

Comment: `rainbowDebug` only shows that `body` is re-evaluated, which doesn’t really mean much by itself. `body` must be re-evaluated because `viewModel` has changed, and this is not expensive for the `body` in your code. If you *do* do expensive things in `body`, show the code and we can discuss further.

Comment: Nah actually I am not doing anything expensive there. My real view just have title, and small image that is in the Assets already. I was just like thinking this generally might be an issue with bigger views.. So I tried to learn the solution for it :) @Sweeper

Comment: Don't use ObservableObject they are so inefficient that Apple created Observable.

Comment: @loremipsum Its iOS17 feature, so not an option yet... (deployment target is 16).

Comment: Then just remove the ViewModel then, it isn't necessary. ObservableObject only has 1 publisher for everything. Therefore the parent and all children are redrawn.

Comment: @loremipsum This isn't unique to `ObservableObject`. Removing `viewModel` and use `selection` as a `@State` directly will exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rainbowDebug` and the Instruments screenshot both show that `body` is called. This *could* be caused by the view being recreated (when the view's *identity* changes), but it could also be caused by changes in one or more of the view's dependencies.

SwiftUI records what dependencies each of your views have. When the dependencies change, the `body`s of the views that depend on those dependencies get evaluated. The new `body` is compared with the previous value of `body`, and SwiftUI figures out the differences, and updates the views accordingly.

Note that this doesn't *recreate* the whole view. In UIKit terms, the change in background color (from `rainbowDebug`) would be similar to just setting the `backgroundColor` property of an existing `UIView` instance. The view is only recreated when its *identity* changes, which would be similar to calling `UIView(frame: ...)` in UIKit terms. To learn more about identities, see [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/). In your code, the identity of `MySelectorView` doesn't change.

From `rainbowDebug`, we can see that `MySelectorView` updates when `viewModel.selection` changes. This is because `viewModel` is a dependency of `MySelectorView`. It is a `@StateObject` in `MySelectorView` after all. This is totally reasonable. Using `@Observable` instead of `Observable` allows SwiftUI to build a much finer-grained dependency graph, and `MySelectorView.body` will not be called.

If you don't want a part of the `body` to run because it doesn't actually depend on anything, you can extract that part into a separate `View`/`ViewModifier`. That `View`/`ViewModifier` would then have no dependencies, and so its `body` will not be called. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78093731/5133585) for an example.

When you select an item, every `MyItemView` is updated. This is unexpected because only the `isSelected` of the selected item and the previously selected item has changed. This can be fixed by not passing a `Binding` to `MyItemView` - just pass a `Bool`, and handle the tap gesture outside of `MyItemView`:

```
struct MyItemView: View {
    
    let model: MyModel
    let isSelected: Bool

    // the rest is the same as before
}
```

```
ForEach(viewModel.types) { model in
    MyItemView (
        model: model,
        isSelected: viewModel.selection == model.type
    )
    .onTapGesture {
        if viewModel.selection == model.type {
            viewModel.selection = nil
        } else {
            viewModel.selection = model.type
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the Binding indeed made a difference, just as you mentioned. I really appreciate detailed explanation! However, I might need to go through it a few more times to fully grasp all the stuff. :)